# Position a div in percentage relative to parent div

Tags: css, css-position, scene

I'm trying to create a scene in css and for that I am using `position: relative` and `position:absolute`.
My problem is that I'm trying to set my child div to the center of my parent div using some css properties and it doesn't seem to work.

Here's what I do :

```
.game {
  background-color: #5386e4;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.fish {
  height: 320px;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin: center; // Here I am trying to set the origin of the div in its center.
  top: 50%;  // And here I am trying to center vertically the child div in the parent div.
  left: 50%; // Same here but horizontally
  z-index: 10000;
  background-color: #10121b;
}
```

Here's what it does
[image]

Note that my div `.game` is also child of another div. Let me know if you need to see more of what is going on in my html or css.

Comment: Can I see some of the HTML code. I think you can achieve this using flex

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use transform property:

```
.fish {
      height: 320px;
      width: 300px;
      position: absolute;
      transform-origin: center; // Here I am trying to set the origin of the div in its center.
      top: 50%;  // And here I am trying to center vertically the child div in the parent div.
      left: 50%; // Same here but horizontally
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      z-index: 10000;
      background-color: #10121b;
    }
```

Or you can also make your parent div `flex` and use `flex-wrap: wrap;` `justify-content:center;` and `align-items:center;` without making child `absolute`

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to add to the .fish div:

```
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex to achieve this

```
.game {
  background-color: #5386e4;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 560;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.fish {
  height: 320px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #10121b;
}
```

Making the "display" => "flex" and then using "justify-content" => "center" && "align-items" => "center" will center the child container perfectly

Comment: I could have used `display: flex` to put the child div in the center of the parent div but I want my child div position to be relative to te parent one. That's why I want to use percentage and positions `absolute` and `relative`

Comment: There's probably a 100 ways to go about achieving your desired result. The solution I gave you still achieves the result in relation to the parent div, same with the solution from Beki

Answer (score -1):

Use `grid` to center anything with `place-content:center;`

Make sure the parent element has enough height to center its children.

```css
body {
    display: grid;
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
}
.game {
    background-color: #5386e4;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    place-content: center;
}

.fish {
    height: 320px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #10121b;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="game">
        <div class="fish"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```